# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 'CannotPullContainerError' for private docker image (multi-instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerhub

I have a single-instance elastic beanstalk environment which runs a docker image which is hosted as a private image on Dockerhub. This works fine. I am trying to create a new multi-container environment which runs the exact same image (plus one other, not icluded in my code example here). In the multi-container environment, I cannot get elastic beanstalk to launch my docker image, I get the following error:

`ECS task stopped due to: Task failed to start. (img1_name: img2_name: CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for user/repo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied)`

Here is the dockerrun for my single-instance environment:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "my_bucket",
    "Key": ".dockercfg"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "user/repo:tag",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 5000,
      "HostPort": 443
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

And here is the .dockerfcg file:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "my_token"
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the above works fine.

My multi-instance dockerrun file is as follows:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "my_bucket",
    "key": ".dockercfg"
  },
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "img_name",
      "image": "user/repo:tag",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 5000
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

I have ssh-ed into my elastic-beanstalk instance and run the following to check that it is able to access the .dockercfg from my s3 bucket:
`aws s3api get-object --bucket mybucket --key dockercfg dockercfg`

I have also tried various different formats for the .dockercfg file including...

```
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "zq212MzEXAMPLE7o6T25Dk0i",
    "email": "email@example.com"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "zq212MzEXAMPLE7o6T25Dk0i"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm tearing my hair out over this, I've found a few similar threads here and on AWS forums, but nothing seems to resolve my issue. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried format with username and password? In [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth-container-instances.html) it says that Docker Hub uses username and password style of auth file?

Comment: Are you using AL2 or AL1?  Is the bucket in the same region? Can you manually pull that image to rule out any non EB issues? Docker version 1.7 and later will use the second form (without email) for the docker config file, and the older versions will use the first.

Comment: did you figure this out ?

Comment: @josephmisiti In the end I got it to work (somehow), but I don't think I ever really figured out what was going wrong. My dockerrun file still looks the same as the (multi-instance) example from my post. The '.dockercfg' file now looks the same as the second example from my post. Perhaps I was using the wrong credentials or something. Not a very clear outcome unfortunately.